# Adding uitableview inside uitableviewcells issues?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[image]I have one iphone application in which i am adding uitableview inside uitableviewcell.in that each uitablecell contains tableview which has dynamic row based upon user's entry.i.e. tableview in first cell contains 3 rows.tableview  in seconds row contains 4 row.thus it varies.my problem is that when i scroll the tableview then entries are repeated.how can i solve that?any tutorial or sample code?

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if(tableView==self.tbView)
    {
        UITableView *tb;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        int height;

    if(cell1==nil)
    {

        cell1=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        tb=[[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cell1.contentView.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain]autorelease];
        tb.rowHeight=50;
        [cell1.contentView addSubview:tb];

            NSMutableArray *a2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                a2=[dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cntt=cntt+1;
            int no=[a2 count]+1;
            height=(no*50);
            heightcnt2=heightcnt2+1;
        NSLog(@"frame of tableviewcontentcell is %@",cell1.contentView.frame);
        tb.frame=CGRectMake(cell1.contentView.frame.origin.x,cell1.contentView.frame.origin.y,cell1.contentView.frame.size.width,height);
        tb.delegate=self;
        tb.dataSource=self;
        tb.tag=tag1;
        tb.scrollEnabled=NO;
        tag1=tag1+1;

    }

        return cell1;


    }   
    else 
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell";


         CategoryListCustomCell *cell = (CategoryListCustomCell *)[[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2]autorelease];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[CategoryListCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2]autorelease];
        }



        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {
            NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            int cmp=[dateArray count];
            if(cnt<=cmp-1)
            {
                temp=[dateArray objectAtIndex:cnt];
                transationObj=[temp objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            NSDate *date=transationObj.tran_date;
            NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
            NSString *strDate=[dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
            cell.lblcatname.text=strDate;
            cnt=cnt+1;

        }

        else 
        {
            transationObj=[[Transaction alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray *temp2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            int cmp2=[dateArray count];
            if(cnt2<cmp2-1)
            {
                temp2=[dateArray objectAtIndex:cnt2];
                for(int i=0;i<[temp2 count];i++)
                {
                    transationObj=[temp2 objectAtIndex:i];
                    cell.lblcatname.text=transationObj.tran_des;

                }



            }
            cnt2=cnt2+1;


        }

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
               return cell;

    }




}
```

I want to create screen like shown in image.where each white section is not same size.its lengh is dynamic as per users entry.so is there any better approach then adding uitableview inside uitableview cell?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "repeated". But I'm curious how you expect scrolling to work with a table inside a table. My experience has been that this won't work unless table 1 only scrolls one direction and table to the other (horizontal vs vertical).

Comment: That is quite a weird behaviour. Could you explain more what you want to do? Maybe you could use only section…

Comment: in this i dont want the tableview which i have embeded inside tableviewcell should scroll.only outer tableview scrolls.this is already clear from code in that you can see that tb.scrollEnabled=NO.and by repeated i mean when i scroll down the recored that are initally displayed are repeated.

Comment: UITableView inside a UITableView? Going for inception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using

```
NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat="CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];
```

instead of
`static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";` in first tableview 
but i know that this will make uitableview to scroll slowly as it is nor reusing CellIdentifier.so it any one can give better solution or better way to make uitableview nested i would appreciate it.

Comment: Why can't you achieve what you want using a grouped table view with sections?